# How to size a modal by ts file ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to size a modal from the TS File and not by the Global SCSS File.

There is a simple code where you size the modal by the Global SCSS File.

**HTML File**

```html
    <ion-content>
      <ion-button expand="block" fill="outline" (click)="onModal()">
        <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-content>
```

**TS File:**

```js
     export class HomePage {

      constructor(private modalController: ModalController) {}

      onModal() {
        this.dynamicPreview('Dynamic Modal');
      }

      async dynamicPreview(info: any) {
        const myModal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: DynamicModalPage,
        cssClass: 'dynamicModalCss',
        componentProps: {
            vInfo: info,
          }
        });
        return await myModal.present();
      }

    }
```

**Global SCSS File:**

```css
    .dynamicModalCss {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        contain: strict;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .modal-wrapper {
            width: 20rem;
            height: 40rem;
          }
    }
```

I have no idea about how to do this :(

Thanks for your suggestions and help

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can customize a modal is using css classes.

Instead of creating the class in the global.scss file, you could create it on each component scss file. In your case, in the HomePage.component.css file.

So, each component will have a different width and height for the modal depending on what you set in the corresponding scss file.

The properties that you have to use are css4 properties: --width, --height.

home.component.scss file

```
.my-modal {
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 50px;
}
```

another.component.scss file

```
.my-modal {
  --width: 100px;
  --height: 50px;
}
```